# Page flipping in PHP

Tags: php, drupal-7, page-flipping

Can anybody tell me how to achieve the page flipping or page turning effect like this: http://viewer.zmags.com/showmag.php?magid=174428#/page28/ for my drupal 7 website?

I've searched for 6 hours but all help I found was in flash but I need it in PHP. Any PHP code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not possible via pure PHP. You'll have to look into Javascript for that.

Answer (score 4):

Usualy you are using javascript or flash for graphical processing, PHP is a serverside language, graphical effects are executed on the client side therefore flash or javascript.

Comment: OK. Do you know about any easy to use JS or jquery script which can do the job with text searching support (i.e. not through images)?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do this in PHP. PHP is for server side coding. The best I can do is point you in the right direction. Javascript is the language you will need an I suggest jQuery if you are not offay with Javascript.

This [link](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/) will give you an example but if you search for jquery page flipping you should find what you need.

Comment: OK. Do you know about any easy to use JS or jquery script which can do the job with text searching support (i.e. not through images)? It will be very good if you had use it yourself.

Comment: sorry no, try the Google Search that I provided